# Apache giving php-fpm error not being ran by default - yet running command says it already is

Tags: php, apache

[image]

I get the above error when doing a sudo apt upgrade.

However when I run the commands it tells me, I get the message that things are already enabled.

[image]

Comment: And is php7.4-fpm in fact already enabled?

Comment: "You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed." It may be that it's not even looking at whether you have 7.4 enabled yet, just outputs those notices regardless.

Comment: Ah, so just default output. That makes sense, and yeah it was already enabled, running the commands it tells me just kept saying "already enabled"

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Edit your question and enter the text, use formatting options to make it readable.

Comment: These are not errors, just post installation messages and if you have already configured your packages, which seems correct in your case, you can ignore these `Notice`s